# Is there a verb that means causing an image in your head?

Tags: word-request

I am not sure if there's a word for that, but I am pretty sure there's something, maybe not a word, but a sort of expression that means that or something similar. It doesn't have to fit a certain context, and I will just provide some examples to clarify what I mean.

For example:

> The humorist used a joke that made the crowd ___, which made them
>   laugh for a long minute or so.
>
> The vivid description made me ___.

Comment: *The vivid description enabled me to **picture** it* (or ***visualize** it*). But I really don't think English would have a single word for the (intransitive, without an explicitly-specified "object") act of having / creating a picture in your mind (or being *caused* to be in that state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression I'd use here is "to paint a picture in someone's mind":

> The comedian made a joke which painted a picture in the crowd's minds, which made them laugh for a long minute or so.
>
> The vivid description painted a picture in my mind.

(However, the first sentence, the one about the comedian, sounds a little weird, because it fails to *describe* the picture which the comedian "painted". Maybe it would sound better with context.)